# how to show image from database in php/mysql. if image is insert in db using C#/Vb.net

Tags: php, mysql

I have Two application one is desktop and other one is web application.

we are storing image in db using desktop application with c#.net/mysql (blob data type in mysql) as  images is capture by signature device.

i want to show that image in web application but its not working. i am using

```
   $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
   if ($im !== false) {
     header('Content-Type: image/png');
     imagepng($im);
     imagedestroy($im);
 }
 else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
 }
```

Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format in

This is how i am saving in DB @

```
Dim myimage As Image
Dim fileName As String = "c:\img.jpg"
myimage.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

Dim imgBytes() As Byte = Nothing
Dim uFileInfo As New IO.FileInfo(fileName)
Dim uFileLength As Long = uFileInfo.Length
Dim uFstream As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim uBinaryReader As New BinaryReader(uFstream)
imgBytes = uBinaryReader.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(uFileLength))


Dim Cmd As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand("update tbl set Sign=? where ID='1', ConnectionString)
Dim param1 As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter
param1 = New OdbcParameter("?", OdbcType.Binary)

param1.DbType = DbType.Binary
param1.Value = imgBytes
param1.Size = imgBytes.Length
Cmd.Parameters.Add(param1)
```

here is the data in Db

---

ÿØÿà JFIF    ÿÛ C

$.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛ C

2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀ  d ú" ÿÄ
ÿÄ µ   } !1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ
ÿÄ µ  w !1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á   #3RðbrÑ
$4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ   ? ÷ú(¢€
(¢€
(¢€
(¢€
(¢€
(¢€
(¢€
Žyáµ‚Iî%H¡K<’0UP:’O TŽ£›n%”<Ží²(cyœôUÏØ I k:
&çRž;Ýt£`ðXFÛ¡„ŽŒÇþZ?¹àvùˆÛwú¯Ë Øæÿ 1åháú¢pòãª{5ðOyójúæ§rßÜµ¬£SþÈ„‡ÿ ¾ªî¥«›IÖÊÎÕïu]Ë6ÕEéºGè‹}IÁÀl¥ý«jœëZ›CkM.G„À¦HßðƒÔ ?á
Òÿ çë\ÿ Áíïÿ £ÉÔ<=ûÕº¸Ô´µûñL<ËˆûÊýdQÝ[-Ü1ÆÒ¨óøræÞ‹©î´Ë™V¥÷Éo#pªÍÕÑŽ–@$†ùwèÍÌÏ‰,R(tt9VAî)õÏéŸñ*ñ-î‘ÒÚé
ý þéÜÈ=ƒ2?ÖSè+  Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( ³õ=PXùpCÚ/çÈ‚Ø6c«1þÛ·A’@,Ö5),£ŽÞÍmFä”¶…º{»c¢.rOÐHÚ^šS#ÜÞÌÚ.åæIHýG8Q€3À iÚC[Üûûƒy¨ºí2•Ú‘)ê‘¯;WêNIÀÃoõvûQÓ4ÅYõ|‚c¶øä#ô^­ì2Á5+ë‰ïWHÓ_eÓ&û‹Œ-c9 àð]ˆ!Aã‚N@Á½a§Ûi–¢ÞÖ=ˆ f$åVbyf'’O&€¦é±i°2«¼³JÛçžN^gþó~@ 8

¹EÏøËþ@–ßöÓô¶è+ŸÔâcâí3Oë
Œm¨N;o9Ž9[ë5ÐP?â¯ôhô½N>'µÔ­£Sê“J°8>Ø“wÕG¥tÏøçåð&»0ûööRÜÆ}52!üA®‚€
(¢€
(¢€
(¢€
(¢€
(¢€
(¢€
(¢€
(¢€
(¢€
(¢€
¡«êcK³‘y÷2¸†Ú peôì:’{ Ojºî‘FÒHÁAff8 ¤Ö€©¹ñÒ÷+‹8Ü¨·<¯™øfÿ €¯ðÐí3L6fK›™~Ñ¨O>|`qÑ
œrNI$³TÔ¥†htûI5€Jå!AÖGÇðŒ€V$9"MOS"8a‹íÓä[Ûƒ‚ØêÌ…F[¶@$š^˜lDÓÏ/ŸrC\OŒdŽŠ£øQyÀ÷$ä’Hšn›™nÈŽòË+™'žO¿3fü€ p  `*åPTõMF-+O’îUgÛ…H“ïJäáQ}É ­.£¨Ã¦Û‰e#»lŠÆ^g=GsÁö H š¥eawww¥¬,k4y6Ö‘¶ä·ÈÁbŠB Æ ÈI`   4M:[i'¼e“Q»:é×‘»¿ì¨Â¦z“Z”Q@ÿ Žÿ äžx—þÁW_ú)« ®Ç?7€õèGßžÆ[xÇ«È¥~,ÀWA@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@6%¼!}m©{åÙHÿ óÍ'‘bgÿ €«–ü+GTÔ£ÒlLÆ6–BDp@Ÿzi
‹õõèIÀ¬ÝCÍ¤Ð]F’[È…eIU”ŽAÏlW ¢_][M§«ÛjWÚtHÑiWpÛµÁò‰ I$iºBî»Fý¤mÊ–a@n‘¦Éh¯uzë6¥p¸˜tˆžˆ¹ ü“É&´ëŸÿ „ãÃ  òÜëv–SÏ½óýšaÿ l¥Úÿ N9£þ5ø·µÖ.ýÏ/HºÚÿ G1„Ç¹l{ÐAYº–³Œ©kOw¨J7EiˆþóÂ'ûGè2p*üTz·Ì=ÔôR«=Ó^¦8Ï·ï?
ÓÓt›M*'[dc$§tÓHÅä™¿¼ìy'ù¦Î·QÔÞ9u]€GŸ.ÝðGž{±åˆ  jQE QE sþ-ýíž›d¿ënu[=ƒ×Ë•goür'®‚¹ø¿âoâù&ëk£)…Ú¹‘Acÿ Œ¨Ïý4aÚº
 (¢Š (¢Š (¢Š (¢Š (¢Š (¢Š (¢Š (¢Š (¢Š (¢Š À× Õ5+*)"  ãk‹â;À¤/þÇî«Ž¸­à€   €Ÿè¾>»–’;Ý:Úfn’Š:±ö5“¥ç‰b[­MåµÓdæ=5FÆ•;Éù¹>XÀ!·v ÑÓµ)5K‰&·³mŠsÖvÏÞOö@‹¨àÚT€Pª  `Ú–€
(¢€
«©jiz|×—¼¸ÇÝQ–rN¨îÄ îH«]MsöŸñ=×ST6™iK2Ý&•Í*@ *·}ÏŽ$×‡4ùôí4»öÙîn¶œ6F.Àà´{ZÔQ@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@ï¬mµ+Gµº|MƒÃe ä2° «È ‚"±ÿ á÷-¯k†Ät´ûf1ÿ m€óÏ>²N˜ÐQ@šo‡´&fžÎÆ4¹q¶K§Ì“È?Û•²íø“ZtQ@Q@2i¢¶‚Iç•"†5.ò;UQÉ$ž‚¨êzæŸ¤´qÜÌMÌ£1[B¦I¥ÿ u$SŒäUkÍf÷íÚÄRÛÚÆÊmtÖ‘HsæK·!›=,«´½ 
Íâƒ…šêYJµï¶"/ýýß¿¾ U
   ©h Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( ¸ˆ¾2Õ<5«øoMÓ…¸MbèÛM+¡gˆeäç†ã÷(¢€;
3F°ÒO±Û…’S™fr^YO«»e˜ýM*¢Š (¢Š (¢Š (¢Š (¢Š (¢Š (¢Š (¢Š ÿÙ

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with imagecreatefromstring function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701238/whats-wrong-with-imagecreatefromstring-function)

Comment: Please show the code how you are saving the image.

Comment: @ChrFin Save Code is posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it might be smarter to upload the images somewhere from your desktop application and only save the file location to the database.

And if you really want to stick to the current implementation you should make a php file to show the image for example image.php

```
// database connection here
// get data from database where id = x 
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($data) . '"/>'
```

EDIT:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: " . $filesize;

// database connection here
// get data from database where id = x 
echo $data;
```

and use it like

```
echo '<img src="image.php?id=x"/>'
```

Comment: @AtifMajeed This should do it can you edit your question and add the code you use for inserting the image in the database?

Comment: @AtifMajeed my vb is very bad but it look sgood compared to other examples i found (i think?), can your try the edit i made?